# Targets containing parent folder `..`

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

If a preqequisite in my makefile refers e.g. to `%/../some.file`, the recipe for `%/../some.file` is not run.

My makefile contains a recipe

```
dir/file:
  recipe

%/file2: %/../file
  recipe
```

where % matches against `dir/subdir`. If I `make dir/subdir/file2`, make complains that it knows `No rule to make target dir/subdir/file2`. Even if I `make dir/subdir/../file`, it knows `No rule to make target dir/subdir/../file`. However, if I `make dir/file` and `make dir/subdir/file2`, everything works fine.

Apparently, referring to parent directories works in prerequisites, but not in targets. Do you know how to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if Make does take the '..' literally as a folder name, not being aware that it refer to a parent folder. Therefore 'file' is not the same as 'subdir/../file'. Technically, this is true, since 'subdir' could be a symlink, but I could not find any reference to this.

Workaround: add a `helper` dependency for each folder

```
dir/%/../file: dir/file
```

It's not perfect, since '%' can match dir/x1/x2/file. But depending on the structure of the source tree, it might be sufficient.

I've noticed that the following will work:

```
dir/subdir/../file: dir/file
```

But it will work only if there are very few files that can be enumerated.